# java web start hangs when trying to start applet in browser

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start, worldwind, next-generation-plugin

I'm trying to start a [NASA World Wind](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/index.html) applet in Firefox. I see the spinning Java logo in the browser, however it hangs after a couple of seconds and I don't see my applet.
I've been trying to enable logging but I see nothing. Things I've tried:-

```
set javaplugin.trace=true in deployment.properties
set TraceBasic=true and other properties in jre/bin/.javawsrc
```

I expected to see something under AppData/LocalLow/Sun/Java/Deployment, but I get no diagnostic messages at all.

I've placed my html, jars (signed), jnlp and required dll files in the same directory, but no applet shows up in the browser, java web start just hangs.

Any ideas for things to try or something to provoke diagnostic messages? I'm getting nothing!

---

Since the [Next Generation Java Plug-in Technology](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/newapplets/) JWS can be used to configure applets that remain embedded in a browser page.  See the [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) & [Applet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) tag information pages for more details.

Here is an [example at the World Wind site](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/demos/index_applet_text_and_links.html).  Note that the JRE reports a problem with the digital certificate, but otherwise the applet loads OK.  The applet element for this applet is..

```
<applet id="wwjApplet" mayscript code="org.jdesktop.applet.util.JNLPAppletLauncher" width=600 height=380
      archive="applet-launcher.jar, worldwind.jar, WWJApplet.jar, http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-webstart-current/jogl.jar, http://download.java.net/media/gluegen/webstart/gluegen-rt.jar">
   <param name="jnlp_href" value="WWJApplet.jnlp">
   <param name="codebase_lookup" value="false">
   <param name="subapplet.classname" value="gov.nasa.worldwind.examples.applet.WWJApplet">
   <param name="subapplet.displayname" value="WWJ Applet">
   <param name="noddraw.check" value="true">

   <param name="progressbar" value="true">
   <param name="jnlpNumExtensions" value="1">
   <param name="jnlpExtension1" value="http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-webstart-current/jogl.jnlp">
</applet>
```

Note the first `param`, the `jnlp_href`.

Comment: May be I'm wrong, but "java webstart" has nothing to do with the browser. The browsers have got thier own java plugin. And they alos have got a java console for outputs. You will get more information if you hover your mouse cursor over the tag.

Comment: You can launch a web start app from the browser since you launch via a URL. I've seen it done that way before.

Comment: Sorry, java webstart indeed has nothing to do with this, it's related to the java browser plugin.

Comment: Well I got something in the Java console. Looks like it can't find class org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
How is the classpath for the browser Java plugin normally configured?

Comment: Got it - add the required jars to the jnlp file. Not forgetting to sign them.

Comment: @All:  There seems to be a lot of confusion in this thread.  See my edit. @OP: You are probably better off trying to **debug** your applet launch outside the browser (yes kids, JWS could launch free-floating applets since 1.2).  Once it works free floating, remove the code base from the JNLP and it should work embedded (in a next-gen. plug-in, at least).